# trigger one MDL dialog with two different buttons

Tags: javascript, dialog, material-design-lite

I'm using the Material Design Lite and I want to trigger one dialog using two different buttons.

I have a working example for one button but I'm not sure how to trigger it with the second button.

Any ideas?

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var dialogButton = document.querySelector('.dialog-button');
  var dialog = document.querySelector('#dialog');
  if (!dialog.showModal) {
    dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);
  }
  dialogButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    dialog.showModal();
  });
  dialog.querySelector('button:not([disabled])')
    .addEventListener('click', function() {
      dialog.close();
    });
}());
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.mdl-dialog {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 9px 46px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 11px 15px -7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 24px 38px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 280px;
}

.mdl-dialog__title {
  padding: 24px 24px 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.mdl-dialog__actions {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 24px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row-reverse;
  -ms-flex-direction: row-reverse;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.mdl-dialog__actions>* {
  margin-right: 8px;
  height: 36px;
}

.mdl-dialog__actions>*:first-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.mdl-dialog__actions--full-width {
  padding: 0 0 8px 0;
}

.mdl-dialog__actions--full-width>* {
  height: 48px;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 100%;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  padding-right: 16px;
  margin-right: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.mdl-dialog__content {
  padding: 20px 24px 24px 24px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dialog-polyfill/0.4.2/dialog-polyfill.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.6/material.indigo-pink.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<button class="mdl-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-button dialog-button">Show Dialog (working)</button>

<br />
<br />

<button class="mdl-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-button dialog-button">Show Dialog (not working)</button>

<br />
<br />

<p>
  Remember that the Dialog component requires the <a href="https://github.com/GoogleChrome/dialog-polyfill">Dialog polyfill</a> in order to function. It takes advantage of the native dialog element to provide the most robust experience possible.
</p>

<dialog id="dialog" class="mdl-dialog">
  <h3 class="mdl-dialog__title">MDL Dialog</h3>
  <div class="mdl-dialog__content">
    <p>
      This is an example of the Material Design Lite dialog component. Please use responsibly.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
    <button type="button" class="mdl-button">Close</button>
  </div>
</dialog>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dialog-polyfill/0.4.2/dialog-polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.6/material.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript querySelector returns the first one if a query returns multiple results. Because of this, you need to make seperate ID's for each button to bind the action to each button.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var dialogButton1 = document.querySelector('#dialog-button-1');
  var dialogButton2 = document.querySelector('#dialog-button-2');

  var dialog = document.querySelector('#dialog');
  if (!dialog.showModal) {
    dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);
  }
  dialogButton1.addEventListener('click', function() {
    dialog.showModal();
  });
  dialogButton2.addEventListener('click', function() {
    dialog.showModal();
  });
  dialog.querySelector('button:not([disabled])')
    .addEventListener('click', function() {
      dialog.close();
    });
}());
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.mdl-dialog {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 9px 46px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 11px 15px -7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 24px 38px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 280px;
}

.mdl-dialog__title {
  padding: 24px 24px 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.mdl-dialog__actions {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 24px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row-reverse;
  -ms-flex-direction: row-reverse;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.mdl-dialog__actions>* {
  margin-right: 8px;
  height: 36px;
}

.mdl-dialog__actions>*:first-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.mdl-dialog__actions--full-width {
  padding: 0 0 8px 0;
}

.mdl-dialog__actions--full-width>* {
  height: 48px;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 100%;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  padding-right: 16px;
  margin-right: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.mdl-dialog__content {
  padding: 20px 24px 24px 24px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dialog-polyfill/0.4.2/dialog-polyfill.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.6/material.indigo-pink.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<button class="mdl-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-button dialog-button" id="dialog-button-1">Show Dialog (working)</button>

<br />
<br />

<button class="mdl-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-button dialog-button" id="dialog-button-2">Show Dialog (now working)</button>

<br />
<br />

<p>
  Remember that the Dialog component requires the <a href="https://github.com/GoogleChrome/dialog-polyfill">Dialog polyfill</a> in order to function. It takes advantage of the native dialog element to provide the most robust experience possible.
</p>

<dialog id="dialog" class="mdl-dialog">
  <h3 class="mdl-dialog__title">MDL Dialog</h3>
  <div class="mdl-dialog__content">
    <p>
      This is an example of the Material Design Lite dialog component. Please use responsibly.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
    <button type="button" class="mdl-button">Close</button>
  </div>
</dialog>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dialog-polyfill/0.4.2/dialog-polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.6/material.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: Why? You can use jQuery to do it with one selector, I can put out a jQuery alternatife if you'd like

Comment: Because I'm not using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

A for loop that cycles through the number of btns with the same selector using queryselectorall.

I first checked if the concept of my idea would work by running this in the console of a page

```
for (i = 0; i != document.querySelectorAll('._card').length; i++) {
    document.querySelectorAll('._card')[i].addEventListener('click', function(args) {
        console.log(args);
    });
}
```

Then once I knew it worked I applied the concept to the code snippets in your question and came up with this,

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var dialogButton = document.querySelectorAll('.dialog-button');
  var dialog = document.querySelector('#dialog');
  if (!dialog.showModal) {
    dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i != dialogButton.length; i++) {
    dialogButton[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        dialog.showModal();
    });
  }
  dialog.querySelector('button:not([disabled])')
    .addEventListener('click', function() {
      dialog.close();
    });
}());
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.mdl-dialog {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 9px 46px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 11px 15px -7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 24px 38px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 280px;
}

.mdl-dialog__title {
  padding: 24px 24px 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.mdl-dialog__actions {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 24px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row-reverse;
  -ms-flex-direction: row-reverse;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.mdl-dialog__actions>* {
  margin-right: 8px;
  height: 36px;
}

.mdl-dialog__actions>*:first-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.mdl-dialog__actions--full-width {
  padding: 0 0 8px 0;
}

.mdl-dialog__actions--full-width>* {
  height: 48px;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 100%;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  padding-right: 16px;
  margin-right: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.mdl-dialog__content {
  padding: 20px 24px 24px 24px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dialog-polyfill/0.4.2/dialog-polyfill.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.6/material.indigo-pink.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<button class="mdl-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-button dialog-button" id="dialog-button-1">Show Dialog (working)</button>

<br />
<br />

<button class="mdl-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-button dialog-button" id="dialog-button-2">Show Dialog (now working)</button>

<br />
<br />

<p>
  Remember that the Dialog component requires the <a href="https://github.com/GoogleChrome/dialog-polyfill">Dialog polyfill</a> in order to function. It takes advantage of the native dialog element to provide the most robust experience possible.
</p>

<dialog id="dialog" class="mdl-dialog">
  <h3 class="mdl-dialog__title">MDL Dialog</h3>
  <div class="mdl-dialog__content">
    <p>
      This is an example of the Material Design Lite dialog component. Please use responsibly.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
    <button type="button" class="mdl-button">Close</button>
  </div>
</dialog>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dialog-polyfill/0.4.2/dialog-polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.6/material.min.js"></script>
 Run
```

You could have done what ilgazer said in his answer above but that requires using many different ids which as you said in a comment was something you wanted to avoid. With this, you could use as many btns as you want and use the same selector.

Comment: I'm Not Sure, Just Force Of Habit I Suppose.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just add a `onclick="dialog.showModal()"` at the second button:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var dialogButton = document.querySelector('.dialog-button');
  var dialog = document.querySelector('#dialog');
  if (!dialog.showModal) {
    dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);
  }
  dialogButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    dialog.showModal();
  });
  dialog.querySelector('button:not([disabled])')
    .addEventListener('click', function() {
      dialog.close();
    });
}());
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.mdl-dialog {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 9px 46px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 11px 15px -7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 24px 38px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 280px;
}

.mdl-dialog__title {
  padding: 24px 24px 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.mdl-dialog__actions {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 24px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row-reverse;
  -ms-flex-direction: row-reverse;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.mdl-dialog__actions>* {
  margin-right: 8px;
  height: 36px;
}

.mdl-dialog__actions>*:first-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.mdl-dialog__actions--full-width {
  padding: 0 0 8px 0;
}

.mdl-dialog__actions--full-width>* {
  height: 48px;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 100%;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  padding-right: 16px;
  margin-right: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.mdl-dialog__content {
  padding: 20px 24px 24px 24px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dialog-polyfill/0.4.2/dialog-polyfill.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.6/material.indigo-pink.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<button class="mdl-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-button dialog-button">Show Dialog (working)</button>

<br />
<br />

<button class="mdl-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-button dialog-button"  onclick="dialog.showModal()">Show Dialog (not working)</button>

<br />
<br />

<p>
  Remember that the Dialog component requires the <a href="https://github.com/GoogleChrome/dialog-polyfill">Dialog polyfill</a> in order to function. It takes advantage of the native dialog element to provide the most robust experience possible.
</p>

<dialog id="dialog" class="mdl-dialog">
  <h3 class="mdl-dialog__title">MDL Dialog</h3>
  <div class="mdl-dialog__content">
    <p>
      This is an example of the Material Design Lite dialog component. Please use responsibly.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
    <button type="button" class="mdl-button">Close</button>
  </div>
</dialog>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dialog-polyfill/0.4.2/dialog-polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.6/material.min.js"></script>
```